# Return values and exceptions

Tags: java, coding-style, source-code, exceptions

I wrote simple function that returns a string depending on which condition is TRUE. Here is my code:

```
private String getMyString() {
    if(!mStrigMember.isEmpty()) {
        return mStrigMember;
    }
    return Function_that_throws_Exception_return_String();
}
```

Because of the Function_that_throws_Exception_return_String I was obliged to add a `try catch` block to end up with:

```
private String getMyString() {
    String TempString = "";
    if(!mStrigMember.isEmpty()) {
        return mStrigMember;
    }
    try {
        TempString = Function_that_throws_Exception_return_String();
    } catch (Exception e) { }
    return TempString ;
}
```

But it's not elegant (TempString is created but not used when the first branch was TRUE). This is my opinion even though it's compiling and working properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What sort of suggestions are you looking for?

Comment: You can simply move the line of declaration down below, and then initialize it to null as opposed to the non-null empty string, and only set it to the non-null empty string inside the catch block. Try moving around your code in various ways, and apply reasoning to see what it would happen under various normal or exceptional flow paths. Just give it a try.

Comment: Someone needs to note that just discarding exceptions is usually a sign of trouble. Of course you may be forced to use an ill-conceived library that (for example) throws exceptions for perfectly valid 'not found' conditions. If so, sucks for you. There's poor design here somewhere. Yours or theirs.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do the following unless there is a good reason not to. The member check acts as a "Guardian Clause" and the need for temp variables disappears if you are returning a constant in the case of an exception.

```
private String getMyString() {
    if (!mStrigMember.isEmpty()) return mStrigMember;

    try {
        return Function_that_throws_Exception_return_String();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

It would be better, if possible, to catch a more specific Exception subclass instead of Exception as Exception includes a whole swag load of runtime exceptions i.e. everything Throwable that is not an Error, which is most likely not what you actually want.

Comment: It was clear and obvious solution, thanks for your understanding and time.

Comment: Doesn't it violate the single entry single exit principle? @Michael